# Handling sharp in the url

Tags: php, regex, url, yii, url-rewriting

I am trying to pass a name variable via this routing pattern.

```
<controller:product>/<name:[^\/]+> => 'product/view'
```

My aim is to get the **$name** in my actionView of the product controller, it works most of the times, but what I've discovered is it fails to pass the name if it contains a sharp (**#**) , for example sending a request

```
 /product/test%20#something
```

Will fail, as far as I understood it is trying to find **actionTest** instead.

It might be a solution to set the default action of the controller to go to the view, but I want a better solution for this. I am sure there is a yii way to solve this.

Also another solution is to **urlencode($productName)**, but it makes the URL look more ugly.

Comment: The hash character `#`, is reserved in urls as the delimiter of a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). If you want to pass that character, you will need to encode it, but many browsers will still parse `%23` as if it were a literal `#`. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904508/handling-sharp-in-the-url#comment-46068624

Comment: I thought there could be a solution to bypass this, but whatever I guess I will just encode it. 

Thanks for the answer.